# Kustomize use helm chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kubectl, kustomize

I want to customize a helm chart with **kustomize**. To start with this topic, I followed their [tutorial on GItHub](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/chart.md) and created a chart like they did in the tutorial. But when I try to build the chart with `kustomize build ./base`, I get this error:

```
Error: json: unknown field "helm-charts"
```

So what am I doing wrong?

I also found a [another plugin for helm](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/guides/extending_kustomize/builtins/#_helmchartinflationgenerator_) in the docs, but the example from this plugin doesn't work eather.

Comment: What version of `kustomize` are you using? Can you show us your actual `kustomization.yaml` file?

Comment: Take a look at [this example](https://github.com/thomastaylor312/advanced-helm-demos/tree/master/post-render). It using customize for Helm [post-renderer feature](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/advanced/#post-rendering)

Answer (score 1):

Problem was the **kustomze** version. As I'm running opensuse, I installed kustomize with zypper. But `kustomize version` didn't show a real version. So now I removed the version provided by zypper and downloaded the binary from the github release page and its working.